# How to use Word Tokenize on a single column in a Data Frame (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I'm trying to use NLTK word_tokenize on an excel file I've opened as a data frame. The column I want to use word_tokenize on contains sentences. How can I pull out that specific column from my data frame to tokenize it? The name of the column I'm trying to access is called "Complaint / Query Detail".

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk import word_tokenize

file = "List of Complaints.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = "All Complaints" )

token = df["Complaint / Query Detail"].apply(word_tokenize)
```

I tried this method but I keep getting errors.

Comment: "But I keep getting errors." And those errors are?

Comment: for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I also tried using word_tokenize in a for loop but still no luck.

Comment: The problem appears to be in the type of column. Can you show us a sample of your dataframe, and the outcome of `print(df.info)` ?

Comment: Is there any way to post screenshots in a comment?

Comment: You can edit your own questions as much as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['Complaint / Query Detail'] = df.apply(lambda row: 
    nltk.word_tokenize(row['Complaint / Query Detail']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a for loop for tokenizing columns in a dataframe.

This is where you see DF put in yoru CSV file

```
def tokenize_text(df):
    for columns in df.columns:
        dataframe["tokenized_"+ columns] = dataframe.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row[columns]), axis=1)
    return dataframe

print(df)
```

I hope it's helpful.